# I need to replace a Domain Group (Office 365 group) with another Domain Group (Office 365 group) on SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, permissions, office-365, csom

I have an Office 365 group added, for e.g. "ABC" which could be present at any of the below level. Permissions are broken at any level below

```
Site
  Document Library
  Pages
    Page 1
    Page 2
  SubSite
```

I need to replace this Office 365 group with another one for e.g. "DEF".
Using Powershell, i can remove the user from the site collection. But because i do that, the user is removed from all places, then i cant find out where the user was present and replace them.

```
          $usrold =$web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName($O365GroupOld)
          $ctx.Load($usrold)
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
          $web.SiteUsers.Remove($usrold)
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
          $usernew=$web.EnsureUser($O365GroupNew)
          $ctx.Load($usernew)
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
          $roleDefinition = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]::Contributor)  
          $roleBindings = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx) 
          $roleBindings.Add($roleDefinition)
          $ctx.Load($web.RoleAssignments.Add($usernew, $roleBindings))
          $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Can someone provide me a powershell script that can replace the Office 365 groups that exists at any level.